# Get real bool value from YamlStream

Tags: yamldotnet

I use YamlDotnet to parse a yaml stream to a dictionary of string object via the YamlStream.
The YamlMappingType, YamlSequenceNode and YamlScalarNode are used in order to convert the value to a dictionary, a list or a string.

But I need to get a real boolean value instead of the string equivalent, and for that I use

```c#
bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out valueBool)
```

value veing a YamlNode.

Is there a better way to do that?
Perhaps another child type of YamlNode?

EDIT:
I don't know the content of the YAML file, I just want to get a dictionary with his values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the parsing manually, you should use the Deserializer class, which will convert a YAML document into an object graph.

```
var deserializer = new Deserializer();
var parsed = deserializer.Deserialize<...>(input);
```

[You can see a working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HD2JXM)

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea of the content of the YAML file.